# What Exactly Does A Constructor Do? (C++)

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor

I am fairly new to the language, and I can't seem to find a good explanation on constructors.

When I don't create a constructor, according to many resources, a default constructor is created, which doesn't do anything. However, is there something that the constructor does behind the scenes that instantiates an object?

A comparison between the default constructor and my own defined constructors would help me understand this.

Thanks a ton in advance!

~novice

Comment: Please read a tutorial or the standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor initializes the variables(fields) of a class. The default constructor initializes to default values. Example, string to "", integers to zero, doubles to 0.0, boolean to false an so on. When you create a constructor you're customizing the variables initialization.

Comment: This could be misleading. For example, `struct S {int i;}; int main() {S s;}` will have an uninitialized `s.i`, not zero.

Comment: Agree with you but, is a more advanced point, and that's confusing the boy who's starting. First the general idea, then move on. :)

Comment: Thanks guys for clarifying! I think I am getting better ideas on what it actually does now.. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

A constructor is essentially the conditions called upon the object being created. If you want to input an int, for example, into the initialization of the object, you would create a constructor that takes "int x" in the parentheses, which is then referenced within the constructor statements.